# Выбор сортировки массива

Tags: javascript, php, html

есть массив который сортируется по цене от наименьшего к большему и наоборот, подскажите пожалуйста, а как можно сделать переключатель из html, чтобы select'om выбирать - наименьшая, наибольшая цена ?

```
<? usort($array,function($a,$b){
$price_asc = $a['product']->price*100 - $b['product']->price*100;
$price_desc = $b['product']->price*100 - $a['product']->price*100; 

return $price_desc;   });?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала добавить самселект в форму (если у вас есть форма)

```
 <select name="order">
     <option value="asc">asc</option>
     <option value="desc">desc</option>
 </select>
```

и учесть этот параметр в пхп-коде: получить из формы, взять значение, или значение по умолчанию.

```
 $x = $_POST['order'];
 $orderValues = ['asc' => 1, 'desc' => -1];
 $order = $orderValues[$x] ?? 1;
```

потом учесть в сортировке

```
 usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($order){
        return $order*($a['product']->price - $b['product']->price);
     });
```

Comment: для двух вариантов сортировки эффективней будет обойтись без массива `$order = $_POST['order'] == 'asc' ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !  Не подскажите , почему может ломаться код тут : $x = $_POST['order'];
 $orderValues = ['asc' => 1, 'desc' => -1];
 $order = $orderValues[$x] ?? 1; Вот весь код :<form action="" method="post" name="form">
  <input value="asc" style="display:none" name="order"> 
  <button type="submit">asc</button> 
 </form>

 <? $x = $_POST['order'];
  $orderValues = ['asc' => 1, 'desc' => -1];
  $order = $orderValues[$x] ?? 1;
 ?>

 <? usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($order){
        return $order*($a['product']->price - $b['product']->price);
     }); 
?>

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Всё работает как надо)